# Inserir em tabelas com chave extrangeira com PDO

Tags: php, pdo

### Como inserir em tabelas com relacionamento um para muitos contendo chave extrangeira

Olá a todos tudo bem estou com uma dúvida, tenho um relacionamento entre duas tabelas no meu bano de dados mysql da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é como vou conseguir fazer a inserção nas duas tabelas já que no meu wireframe como requisito é solicitado isso, então o meu formulário eu tenho o seguinte:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h2>Painel de inserção de imagens</h2>
            <input class="btn btn-success" required="" type="file" name="fileUpload" id="passaValor" title="inserir imagens"> <br></br>
            <label>Qual Pagina deverá ser exibida</label>


            <select required="" name="id_pagina">
                
                <?php
                    $daoPagina->selecionaTodasPaginas();
                ?>
            </select>
            

            <label>Titulo, Coloque até 50 letras</label>
            <input class="input-xxlarge" type="text" name="titulo" required=""> <br/><br/> 
            <label>Descrição total das imágens não poupe suas palavas</label>
            <textarea class="input-xxlarge" name="textoDaImagem" required="" rows="5"> </textarea><br></br>


            <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>
```

Bom a questão de inserção de imagens está sucinta pra mim, o que eu gostaria de saber é, como vou passar o id_imagem nesse ponto do meu código:

```
$daoDescricaoImagem = new DescricaoImagemEntity("", $titulo, $textoDaImagem, 42);
```

onde se lê o numero 42 seria onde eu gostaria de passar meu id_imagem nesse caso passei ele sem ser dinâmico para testar, o processo é o seguinte eu insiro minha imagem e depois quero inserir minha descrição de imagem justamente para essa imagem.

se alguém tiver uma sugestão agradeço, estou utilizando PDO.

Comment: As informações estão em form diferentes?

Comment: não estão no mesmo form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No método de insert da imagem retorne o id do registro inserido com [lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php), guarde esse valor em uma variável ou objeto e passe ele para `DescricaoImagemEntity`.

DAO imagem

```
public function insertImagem($imagem){
   //código do insert
   $smtm->execute(); 
   return $this->connection->lastInsertId(); 
}
```

Arquivo que salva as informações:

```
<?php
 $daoImagem = new DAOImagem();

 //$imagem é uma objeto populado com as informas de $_POST
 $id_imagem = $daoImagem->insertImagem($imagem); 
 $daoDescricaoImagem = new DescricaoImagemEntity("", $titulo, $textoDaImagem, $id_imagem);
```

Comment: sempre o senhor respondendo minhas dúvidas, dessa vez tinha passado perto de acertar a resposta. tinha colocado return $smtm->lastInsertId(); obrigado.

Comment: @AndréMartins, está usando o mysql ou postgres?

Comment: mysql, postgres utilizo mais com java

Comment: por que a dúvida? @rray

Comment: @AndréMartins, o postgres tem algo bacana que é bom saber que é clásula [returning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) que retorna o id inserido já no insert dai não precisa chamar `lastInsertId` mas o mysql não tem isso :P

Comment: que massa... acrescentando isso né RETURNING meu_id, meu ingles tá fraco é por isso que não tinha funcionado...

Comment: quando estava lendo a documentação não percebi :(