# Pegar id de uma gravação anterior

Tags: php

Boa tarde. Tenho um formulário simples de uma agenda que grava os dados de local, nome do evento e etc, em seguida tenho um outro que grava os usuário participantes, gostaria de saber como pego a ID desse formulário anterior (gravação de eventos). Para gravar no formulário de participantes, e depois pode relacionar.

Gravação primeiro formulário

```
Case 'salvar';

    $data = '';
    $data = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', $_POST['data_agenda'])));

                    if (app::$key) {
                        $sql = "update agenda set compromisso_agenda='" . $_POST["compromisso_agenda"] . "'
                                                ,data_agenda='$data',hora_agenda='" . $_POST["hora_agenda"] . "',pessoa_agenda='" . $_POST["pessoa_agenda"] . "',local_agenda='" . $_POST["local_agenda"] . "' where id_agenda=" . app::$key;
                    } else {
                        $sql = "insert into agenda (compromisso_agenda,data_agenda,hora_agenda,pessoa_agenda,local_agenda)
                                       values ( '" . $_POST["compromisso_agenda"] . "','$data','" . $_POST["hora_agenda"] . "','" . $_POST["pessoa_agenda"] . "','" . $_POST["local_agenda"] . "')";
                    }

                    $dados = connection::exec($sql);

                    header('Location: ' . URL . 'agenda/pessoas');
                    break;
```

Gravação segundo formuário

```
case 'salvar-pessoa':

$agendap_id = fetchColumn(0);

                if (app::$key) {
                    $sql = "update agendap set agendap_id='$agendap_id',agendap_pessoa='" . $_POST["agendap_pessoa"] . "' where id_agenda=" . app::$key;
                } else {
                    $sql = "insert into agendap (agendap_id,agendap_pessoa)
                                   values ( '$agendap_id','" . $_POST["agendap_pessoa"] . "')";
                }

                $dados = connection::exec($sql);

                header('Location: ' . URL . 'agenda/exibir');
                break;
```

Comment: Ou ainda [Inserir em tabelas com chave extrangeira com PDO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60978/91)

Answer (score -2):

Se você estiver utilizando MySQL, você pode utilizar a função mysql_insert_id(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php